# Tkinter Reminder MessageBox Show up

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I am trying to create a reminder using Tkinter.

I can give the appropriate time and the same time change a label's text,but I want to show up a MessageBox,too.

My code is below:
(I am get an error like: "TkMessageBox not defined")

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import time


    form1=Tk()
    form1.title('Project')
    form1.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    form1.geometry('1032x680+200+200')

    time1 = ''
    clock = Label(form1, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='red')
    clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    def tick():
        global time1
        time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        if time2 != time1:
            time1 = time2
            clock.config(text=time2)
        clock.after(200, tick)
    tick()
    reminder = Label(form1, font=('remind', 20, 'bold'),bg='green')
    reminder.pack(fill=BOTH , expand=1)
    reminder.config(text="o reminder")
    def hour():
        global x,y,z
        x=float(time.strftime("%H"))
        y=float(time.strftime("%M"))
        z=float(time.strftime("%S"))
        if y==37: reminder.config(text="First")
        if y==38:                       
            reminder.config(text="Second") 
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(text='Something',message='Else') 
        reminder.after(200,hour)

    hour()

    form1.mainloop()
```

If I comment the:

```
  tkMessageBox.showinfo(text='Something',message='Else')
```

..everything is ok.

But how can I show up a Messagebox...??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`tkMessageBox` is actually it's own module. You need to separately import the tkMessageBox.

```
import tkMessageBox
```

In addition, it appears you need to pass the Tkinter loop to the message box:

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo(form1,text='Something',message='Else')
```

Comment: I know this, but I forgot to write it in my code.
    Nevermind, this is not my problem.
    Import the tkMessageBox or not the program shows error.
    What I have to do..?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. The trick is to import from the tkinter package directly as follows:

```
import tkinter.messagebox as MB
```

then in order to use the message box:

```
MB.showinfo("heading text","body message")
```

I hope this helps!!